# BirtView BeanNameViewResolver with content type "text/html"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, birt

I am using the BIRT API to render reports in a jsp. The jsp makes calls via javascript and ajax to load the report content. My custom BirtView and BirtEngineFactory are registered as beans.

My BeanNameViewResolver never gets tried because the InternalResourceViewResolver in the ContentNegotiationViewResolver returns a 404 when it fails to find a matching .jsp or .html file.

Is it possible to have the BeanNameViewResolver serve "text/html" without setting its Order higher than ContentNegotationViewResolver? ie if no matching .jsp or .html file is found then the BeanNameViewResolver would be tried before returning a 404.

Answer (score 0):

When [chaining view resolvers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (see chaining ViewResolvers), `InternalResourceViewResolver` always has to be last because it is always automatically positioned as the last resolver in the chain.
So make sure your `BeanNameViewResolver` is defined before  `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Comment: It does not have to be last because you can set its ordered property. For example, our `JsonViewResolver` is last. We did end up choosing to put it after `BeanNameViewResolver`, because we could not find a concise solution putting `InternalResourceViewResolver` before it.